# Chart labels overlap with error bars using the Above function, How can I move the labels slightly more above?

Tags: labeling, charts

I need a combination of these two charts.  I also cannot seem to get the labels "Above" the bars "Above" enough.  They run into the error bars.  When I added the counts (n = 1), the horizontal percentages no longer showed up.  I do not know what else to try at this point.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image: This one is missing the percentage labels that are shown in the second picture, and the Above chart labels are not "Above" enough, they run into the error bars. I need a combination of the two charts.]

[image: This one does not have the other call outs, but the axis labeling is correct. Need to add this to the first picture.]

```
errorBar[type_: "Rectangle"][{{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}}, value_, 
  meta_] := Block[{error}, error = Flatten[meta];
  error = 
   If[error === {}, 0, 
    Last[error]]; {ChartElementData[type][{{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}, value,
     meta], {Black, 
    Line[{{{(x0 + x1)/2, y1 - error}, {(x0 + x1)/2, 
        y1 + error}}, {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), 
        y1 + error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), 
        y1 + error}}, {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), 
        y1 - error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), y1 - error}}}]}}]

chartData = {14.77 -> 0.40832775506393815, 
   21.72 -> 0.12547384934195213, 20.22 -> 0.8224165242709678, 
   23.67 -> 0.3050610139336427, 20.88 -> 0.30377788713067355, 
   21.61 -> 0.9151942113259043, 18.23 -> 0.37645953006635097, 
   21.73 -> 0.3079566058897114, 26.33 -> 1.1410094954731147, 
   17.42 -> 0.4769719831680606, 18.86 -> 0.5250479766438282, 
   9.67 -> 0.7727768700660568, 11.05 -> 0.8229443075526639, 
   2.09 -> 0.24377502461544875};

labels = {"0%" , "0%" , "0.1%" , "0.1%" , "0.2%" , "0.2%", "1.0%" , 
   "1.0%" , "11.35%",  "2.5%" , "2.5%" , "5.0%" , "5.0%" , "10%"}; 

BarChart[chartData, ChartElementFunction -> errorBar["Rectangle"], 
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 487.5, 
 ChartStyle -> {{Yellow, Orange, Blue, GrayLevel[0.30], Blue, 
    GrayLevel[0.30], Blue, GrayLevel[0.30], Red, Blue, 
    GrayLevel[0.30], Blue, GrayLevel[0.30], Blue}}, 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[ SwatchLegend[{Yellow, Orange, Blue, GrayLevel[0.30], 
     Red}, {"\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Processed polymer\
\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]", 
     "\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Measured \
polymer\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]", 
     "\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Randomly \
oriented\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]", 
     "\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Multi-line\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]", 
     "\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Single-line\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]"}], 
   Top], ChartLabels -> {Placed[labels, Axis, 
    Rotate[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Times"], Pi/2] &], 
   Placed[{"n = 1", "n = 1", "n = 1", "n = 1", "n = 1", "n = 1", 
     "n = 1", "n = 1", "n = 1", "n = 1", "n = 1", "n = 1", "n = 1", 
     "n = 1"}, Center]}, Frame -> Left, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, 
   Style["Ultimate tensile strength, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \
\(\(UT\)\(\\\ \)\)]\)[MPa]", FontFamily -> "Times"]}, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[N[#/Total@1], Above] &)]
```

[image: Has most of the elements that I need, but the n=#, needs to have the actual number, not just a consecutive count.]

I'm still trying to get this to work.  I can't get the actual count (n=#) to show up in my plot. They have actual values that are not consecutive as shown. I've tried adding them as a string, I've also tried adding them into the errorBarWithLabel function.

Comment: Can you post copyable code? The pictures are nice, but the code is important.

Comment: I tried to add code, but it won't copy correctly. Tried copying as input text, that also did not work.

Comment: Ok. post it anyway, we'll see what we can do to fix it.

Comment: It exceeds the character limit.

Comment: Hmm. What is needed then is a minimum working example, i.e. strip out anything that is not needed to demonstrate the problem. A brief look suggests that all of the options but `ChartElementFunction`, `Frame`, and `LabelingFunction` can be removed. Also, post a `chartData` with only 3 or 4 data points, just enough to demonstrate the issue, but not enough to overwhelm the system.

Comment: oh, and we'll need the code for `errorBar`, too, or where you got it from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the function `errorBar` to add the bar labels above the error bars:

```
ClearAll[errorBarWithLabel]
errorBarWithLabel[type_: "Rectangle", shift_: .025, 
   style_: {12, "Panel"}][{{x0_, x1_}, {y0_, y1_}}, value_, meta_] := 
 Block[{error}, error = Flatten[meta]; error = If[error === {}, 0, Last[error]];
  {ChartElementData[type][{{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}, value, meta], {Black, 
    Line[{{{(x0 + x1)/2, y1 - error}, {(x0 + x1)/2, y1 + error}}, 
         {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), y1 + error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), y1 + error}}, 
         {{1/4 (3 x0 + x1), y1 - error}, {1/4 (x0 + 3 x1), y1 - error}}}], 
    Text[Style[value, ## & @@ style], {(x0 + x1)/2, y1 + error + shift}]}}]
```

Examples:

```
data = Flatten @ MapThread[{#1 -> #2} &, {RandomReal[1, 10], RandomReal[0.1, 10]}];
labels = StringJoin @@@ RandomChoice[CharacterRange["a", "z"], {10, 6}];
labelF = Placed[Row[{"n = ", #2[[2]]}, "  "], Center] &;

BarChart[data, LabelingFunction -> labelF, ImageSize -> 500, ChartStyle -> 1,
   ChartLabels -> {None, Placed[labels, Axis, Rotate[Style[#, 18, "Panel"], Pi/2] &]},
  ChartElementFunction -> errorBarWithLabel[]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Use the setting `errorBarWithLabel["FadingRectangle", .025, {Bold, Italic, 12, Red, "Panel"}]` to get:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Looks like this will probably work.  I am going to implement and see if I can get it to go.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @LeoraHomel, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: I can't figure out how to change the n values to the actual count values that I need.  I tried to modify the errorBarwithLabels function to include a third variable, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Any thoughts @kglr?

Comment: @Leora, in your original code the `n` values were hard-coded as `1` for each bar? In my code, (meant as a placeholder) they are the indices of the bars. Could you explain how `actual count values` are related to input data (`chartData`)?

Comment: chartData holds the mean of the actual data. The data itself consists of the 14 different sample types, of which have varying lengths.

Comment: @Leora, with   `counts= Length/@theDataItself` you can modify `labelF` to `labelF = Placed[Row[{"n = ", counts[[#2[[2]]]]}, "  "], Center] &;` to show the sample sizes in the centers of the bars (which, I see now in your self-answer, you did already:)). Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the second issue by putting the count data into a variable, n, then calling it in the labelcount variable.

```
labelcount = Placed[Row[{"n=", n[#2[[2]]], ""}], Center] &;

BarChart[chartData, ChartElementFunction -> errorBarWithLabel[], 
 LabelingFunction -> labelcount, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> myImageSize, 
 LabelStyle -> myAxesStyle, 
 ChartStyle -> {{Yellow, Orange, Blue, GrayLevel[0.30], Blue, 
    GrayLevel[0.30], Blue, GrayLevel[0.30], Red, Blue, 
    GrayLevel[0.30], Blue, GrayLevel[0.30], Blue}}, 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[ SwatchLegend[{Yellow, Orange, Blue, GrayLevel[0.30], 
     Red}, {"\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Processed polymer\
\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]", 
     "\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Measured \
polymer\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]", 
     "\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Randomly \
oriented\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]", 
     "\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Multi\[Hyphen]line\
\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]", 
     "\[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]Single\[Hyphen]line\
\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote]"}], Top], 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[labels, Axis, 
    Rotate[Style[#, FontFamily -> "Times"], Pi/2] &]}, Frame -> Left, 
 FrameLabel -> {None, 
   Style["Ultimate tensile strength, \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Sigma]\), \
\(\(UT\)\(\\\ \)\)]\)[MPa]", myScaledAxesFontSize, 
    FontFamily -> "Times"]}]
```